# creating an alias for existing key

Tags: expl3, l3keys

In there an easy way to define an alias for an existing key which does exactly the same, but without the need to duplicate the code of the existing key? That is, something like:

```
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
{
  mykey .code:n = Some~code~for~key~`mykey',
  myalias .same_as:n = mykey
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a meta key:

```
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
  {
    mykey   .code:n = Some~code~for~key~`mykey',
    myalias .meta:n = { mykey = #1 }
  }
```

Comment: And if `mykey` requires an argument, will `myalias` do the same automatically?

Comment: @AlexG No, any error would come from the 'master' key: meta keys are a short-cut for passing the input effectively to a `\keys_set:nn` command.